# Обновление бота на сервере

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

У меня есть бот, который хостится на сервере.
Бот запущен через systemctl.

**Проблема**: обновление бота
Сейчас порядок обновления кода следующий ->

1. загрузка обновленного кода на сервер через Filezilla
2. вход на сервер по ssh и рестарт systemctl с ботом

Нет ли каких-то более удобных способов? В идеале, чтобы бот сам забирал последнюю версию кода с гитхаб репозитория и перезапускал сервис

Comment: функциональность бота можно вынести отдельно и обновлять только ее без перезапуска и остановки бота (своеобразный [CI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: напишите один раз скрипт, который выгрузит на сервер код, перезапустит все что нужно и сделает минимальные проверки, что оно работает.  Вместо Filezilla можно использовать scp, перезапуск - ssh (внутри того, что Вы заливаете на сервер может быть ещё один скрипт, который на сервере все сделает. а запустить его с своей локальной машины можно где то так ssh <server_name> /your/script/py)

Comment: Лично я делаю все упомянутые действия с помощью Ansible-плейбука. Пытаться научить бота самообновляться — скорее всего плохая идея

Comment: playbook - тоже хорошая штука, все зависит только от знаний и возможностей. Я для своих приложений в make файл добавлял. И там прям было deploy - он запускало на gitlab задачу. которая собирала все, выкладывала куда нужно и писала письмо QA, что новая версия вышла, пофикшены такие то баги. И это все одной командой в консоли.

Comment: Звучит более чем разумно, может как ответ оформите? Я искал что то подобное, но из-за лени и второстепенности задачи откладываю данную реализацию